# How can I write the equivalent of an Imagemagick command line in magick c++?

Tags: c++, image, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

This ImageMagick command line works:

```
convert transparent.png -alpha remove transparent.jpg
```

How can I achive the equivalent of the above using magick c++ code. I tried

```
image.alpha(false)
image.backgroundColor(Color("WHITE"))
```

But that does not seem to work.

Comment: AFAIK, JPEG doesn't support transparency. Saving an image with alpha channel as JPEG should remove the alpha "for free", shouldn't it?

Comment: I thought so. Apparently thats not happening and JPEG image looks messed up because of this. So I need to manually remove alpha whenever transparent png is being viewed as JPEG or any non-png format. I am new to this image magic/c++. So my knowledge is limited on this.